# Open View Controller with respect to Section header index in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I'm working in the table view in which there are two section headers in an array, the first section has no name its empty and second has name Library. I have items in the table view which are also in an array, but the array is multidimensional. I have given all the delegates and data source methods of table view that are necessary. But when I try to open the view controller through deselect method through the items under Section2 header, it open the view controller of items under section 1. My arrays are defined like this,

```
 var menuImages = [["drawerlogin","drawerhome", "drawerquestions", "drawerupload","drawerfalshcard"], ["drawermylibrary","drawermydocs", "drawermyflashcard", "drawermyquestions"]]
var menuItems = [["Login","Home", "Ask A Question", "Upload Document","Create FlashCard"], ["My Library","My Documents", "My FlashCards", "My Questions"]]
var sectionTitles = ["", "Library"]
```

Delegates and datasource methods are these,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section < sectionTitles.count {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }
    return nil
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems[section].count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = drawerTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DrawerTableViewCell
   cell.titleLbl.text = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
   cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: menuImages[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 60
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if sectionTitles[0] == "" && indexPath.row == 0
    {
            let ide = "LoginViewController"
            let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ide)
            self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
    else  if sectionTitles[0] == "" && indexPath.row == 1

    {
        let tbc = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController
        tbc?.selectedIndex = 0
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.left, animated: true)
    }else  if sectionTitles[0] == "" && indexPath.row == 2
    {
        let tbc = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController
        tbc?.selectedIndex = 4
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.left, animated: true)
    }else if sectionTitles[0] == "" && indexPath.row == 3
    {
        let tbc = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController
        tbc?.selectedIndex = 1
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.left, animated: true)
    }else if sectionTitles[0] == "" && indexPath.row == 4
     {
            let tbc = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController
            tbc?.selectedIndex = 2
            self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.left, animated: true)
    }
    if sectionTitles[1] == "Library" && indexPath.row == 5{

        let tbc = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController
        tbc?.selectedIndex = 3
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.left, animated: true)
    }else if sectionTitles[1] == "Library" && indexPath.row == 6{
        let ide = "MyDocsViewController"
        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ide)

     self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }else if sectionTitles[1] == "Library" && indexPath.row == 7{

        let ide = "MyFlashCardViewController"
        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ide)
         self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }else if sectionTitles[1] == "Library" && indexPath.row == 8{

        let ide = "MyQuestionViewController"
        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ide)
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }

   }
```

The application also crashes when we scroll the table view to the bottom and it shows error,

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

The table view looks like this,
[image]

Comment: your code was not correct you have to change it in didselect delegate method

Answer (score 0):

in didSelectRow compare section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
         print(menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
        // here you got all click of first section
    }else{
       // here you got all click of Second section
         print(menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
          let vcTab : TabOrbexController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabOrbexController") as! TabOrbexController
          vcTab.selectedIndex = 1
          NavigateToView(vc: vcTab)
    }


}

func NavigateToView(vc: UIViewController){
        let navigationController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(navigationController , animated:true)
    }
```

Comment: Bro, when i open the view controllers from section == 1 it open properly but when i click any item under section 0 it is now open the same view controllers that are in section 1. @

Sh_Khan

Comment: @Hamza try above solution just replace your did select delegates method

Comment: @Hamza code in  first comparison of  if sectionTitles[1] == "Library" && indexPath.row == 5{.  should be indexPath.row == 0.  in section 1 and so on

Comment: I have tried ur code but it isn't working fine. @Sh_Khan

Comment: @Hamza did you update your question with latest code that you made changes

Comment: it seems that you have a problem with indexpath.row for every section it starts with zero

Comment: I think its issue because of view controller, some view controllers are having tab bar at the bottom which is opened through the tab bar index . and other view controllers are simple without tab bar at the bottom they are opened through storyboard identifier. Compiler might be confused after opening the view controller that is simple how to open tab bar contrller VC. @Sh_Khan

Comment: i m using same code in my project and its working fine @Hamza